# Eclipse plugin : Get the enclosing class and member name

Tags: eclipse, plugins, breadcrumbs

I have created a Eclipse plug in  to printout the object in selection on press of a short cut key.
I have been able to do this ,but i also would like to add the current method and current class name in the log. I am not sure how to proceede further. I tried to search for breadcrumb API but i was not able to reference the package from my project. I am quite new to plugin developement could someone guide me as to how to achive my goal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really hard to get that stuff from Breadcrumb, you would have to use reflection to get it.

Here is the code to get current method from editor.

```
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
        .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();

ITextSelection selection = (ITextSelection) editor
        .getSelectionProvider().getSelection();

IEditorInput editorInput = editor.getEditorInput();
IJavaElement elem = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editorInput);
if (elem instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
    ICompilationUnit unit = (ICompilationUnit) elem;
    IJavaElement selected = unit.getElementAt(selection.getOffset());

    System.out.println("selected=" + selected);
    System.out.println("selected.class=" + selected.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped me a lot. I would appreciate if you could share some links where in i can learn more of these.