# Get selected Java Element from editor in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, selection

I am working on an eclipse plugin, and I need to get the selected element from the active editor.  I have already figured out (one way) to do this.  Here are the key lines:

```
ITypeRoot root = EditorUtility.getEditorInputJavaElement(activeJavaEditor, false);
selectedElement = root.getElementAt(offset);
```

(This is similar to the answer the question [Eclipse plugin : Get the enclosing class and member name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953096/eclipse-plugin-get-the-enclosing-class-and-member-name))

But the problem that I'm having is that this will only return declared methods, types, fields, etc, and never invoked ones.  For example, given this code in the active editor:

```
public void foo() {
    ClassA.run();
}
```

even if the caret is positioned over "ClassA" or "run," my code still returns the method "foo."  Does anyone know how to also get invoked methods?

Comment: This thread may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453617/how-can-i-get-the-selected-code-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ITypeRoot#codeSelect() instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `Class#method()` notation. Could you please clarify? Where in @Reyan's code should this call go?

Comment: '#' is just a variant of '.'  In this case, it just means to call codeSelect() on an object of type ITypeRoot.  Thus I replaced "root.getElementAt(offset)" with "root.codeSelect(offset, length)"